# Standard way to deploy a fabric-CA cluster

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying run fabric-ca as cluster with mysql as backend and recently came across this [link](https://github.com/trinayanbhatt/LDAP-mysql-fabric) where both ca0 and ca1 are started with a same cert and key file

but as per the [official doc](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#setting-up-multiple-cas) a **ca cluster** can be started by using either ca-count or cafile option where every such instance have there own unique cert an key.

can anyone share your view on this and a proper way provision a ca-cluster for High Availability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to have a "cluster" of fabric-ca servers which share the same root key pair.  But I would not actually use a top-level root certificate for this.  I would actually create a root CA and then have it issue an intermediate CA cert which the fabric-ca servers would then use.  You should then protect the initial root CA key pair offline.